# Make one layout inside the main layout invisible when we click other area on the main layout

Tags: android

I have one custom listview containing imagebuttons and textviews. Right now when I click on the info icon, it opens up the pop up(which is actually a layout that I am making visible on the imagebutton's click) that gives some description and when I click on that icon again it becomes invisible. But I want it to make invisible whenever I click on any other area and not just on that info icon.

```
//img_Info is the Imagebutton containing i icon
img_Info = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.img_Info);

img_Info.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       //llimg_info is the linearlayout that becomes visible on the click event  
       if(llimg_info.isShown()) {
        llimg_info.setVisibility(llimg_info.INVISIBLE);
       }
       else {
        llimg_info.setVisibility(llimg_info.VISIBLE);
       }
   }
});
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Please see my answer, it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code for check visibility of ImageView, it will solve your problem.

```
ImageView llimg_info = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_Info);

if (llimg_info.getVisibility() == 0) {
    System.out.println("Visible");
    llimg_info.setVisibility(llimg_info.INVISIBLE);
} else{
    System.out.println("Invisible");
    llimg_info.setVisibility(llimg_info.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: it does the same thing as it was doing with llimg_info.isshown()................. means when I click on info it becomes visible and when i click on that again it becomes invisible; but I want that it should become invisible even if I click on any other area and not only that info icon.

Comment: @nidhi Then set visibility to invisible on click event of main layout.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will help, but try to register a focus change listener for your pop-up, so that when it will loose focus to make it invisible.

Something like this:

```
thePopup.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (!hasFocus) {
            thePopup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
});
```